# How to: foreach without affecting every row?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Is there a way to do a foreach on for example your products and sort this by their category_id and show the category name above the products. (I'm using laravel 4 as framework)

Example what the output should look like:

```
Chairs

 wooden chair number 1

 pretty chair number 1

 pretty chair number 2

Doors

 tall door number 1

 white door number 1
```

Key question: How can i make a foreach without having the categoryname above each row ?

Hopefully i made my question/problem clear and can someone help me out!

This is what i got so far:

Though, when i do my foreach in the blade i will get the error: " Undefined index "

The foreach i used in my controller:

```
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $category[$result->category_id][] = $result;
    }
```

My foreach in the blade:

```
    @foreach ($category as $key => $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product[$key]['created_at'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product[$key]['order_id'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product[$key]['name'] }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: What's the output you're getting? The error message?

Comment: Undefined index: (mybladefile)      ----- and when i fill in the instead of $key a 0 or 1 it works. But when i var_dump the $key it outputs 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are attempting to use category_id to fetch $product from $products, which is array with 0-X indexes. for sake of simplicity i will ignore html formatting and syntax since i never used framework mentioned...

```
@foreach ($category as $key => $products)
       echo 'Category #', $key

       @foreach ($products as $product)
       <tr>
        <td>{{ $product['created_at'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product['order_id'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product['name'] }}</td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: This should be the solution. I was going to mention that he had incorrectly used the $key on the wrong index (used on $product instead of $category)

Comment: That is the solution indeed, atleast as far as i can tell. Thank you !!

Comment: I'm celebrating too early :P The names of the categories underneath the first foreach (your echo that is). Will all output under each other instead of under each loop of products. How can i fix that :S

Comment: it should output something like

category_id
  -products

category_id
  -products.
if you want category name you would have to change echo $key into something like $products[0]['category_name'] if you have that in your variable that is.

Comment: What i needed to do was $products[0]->category->name! Thanks @vertazzar for your tip solving this problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

not completely sure i understand the question.  but if im trying to organize an array.. i might use a conditional statement inside the foreach loop.  I'm not sure your question is very clear..  see if this helps at all

```
foreach($results as $result) {

    // just an example.. i narrow down what I push into my category array
    if($result->type == 'whatever'){
        $category[$result->category_id][] = $result;
    }

}
```